# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: client is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm encountering an error while making a command for my discord.js bot which says `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: client is not defined` even tho i defined client in the main bot file so i'm pretty confused the code for the command i'm making:

```
    let ticketGen = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".split("");
    let ticketStr = "";

    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ticketStr += ticketGen[Math.floor(Math.random() * ticketGen.length)];
    }

    return ticketStr;
}
const fsn = require("fs-nextra");

const colors = require("colors");


module.exports = {
    name: 'order',
    description: 'Ordering something',
    aliases: ['o'],
    execute(message) {
        let order = message.content.substring(8);
        let customer = message.author.id

        fsn.readJSON("./blacklist.json").then((blacklistDB) => {
            let entry = blacklistDB[message.guild.id];
            
            // Checks is server is blacklisted or not.
            if(entry === undefined) {
                // Gets ticket ID.
                const ticketID = generateID();
        
                // Sends ticket information to tickets channel.
                client.guilds.cache.get("745409671430668389").channels.get("746423099871985755").send({embed: {
                    color: 0xFFFFFF,
                    title: message.author.username,
                    fields: [{
                        name: "New Order",
                        value: `${message.author.username} would like to order something.`,
                    }, {
                        name: "Order Description",
                        value: order,
                    }, {
                        name: "Order ID",
                        value: ticketID,
                    }, {
                        name: "Guild Infomation",
                        value: `This order came from ${message.guild} (${message.guild.id}) in ${message.channel} (${message.channel.id}).`,
                    }, {
                        name: "Order Status",
                        value: "Unclaimed", 
                    }],
                    timestamp: new Date(),
                    footer: {
                        text: "Taco Bot"
                    }
                }}).then((m) => {
                    m = m.id;
//rest of the code
```

forgive me if it was an stupid error i'm completely new to coding and was watching youtube videos to learn the code for the main bot file:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { prefix, token, ownerID } = require('./config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`ready!.`);
    console.log(token);
    

    // Activities  
    const activities_list = [ 
        `Serving Tacos | .help`,
        `Preparing Orders | .help`
    ];
    
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1);
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]);
    }, 10000);

    
});


//Joined Guild
client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {   
    console.log(colors.green(`Joined New Guild, ${guild.name}`));
});

//Left Guild
client.on("guildDelete", (guild) => {
    console.log(colors.green(`Left Guild, ${guild.name}`));
});


client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }



    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

process.on("error", () => {
    console.log("Oops something happened!");
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Well you might have defined it in the main bot file, but that doesn't make it available in the `execute` scope. Pass it as an argument, next to the `message`  parameter.

Comment: i think this fixed it but now im encountering `const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include how you fixed it? But no, I can't see how `client.commands` can be `undefined` after `client.commands = new Discord.Collection();`. Maybe you created a separate client?

Comment: yep i created a separate client which made it worse i think

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a new `client`, and absolutely no need to pass it in as an additional argument in your `execute` method. As you have seen in the comments, the issue is that while `client` is defined in your main bot file, it is not defined in your command's file. Variables defined in one file aren't accessible in all other files, unless you specifically export that variable using `module.exports`.

But luckily, you don't need to export your `client` or pass it as a parameter; discord.js conveniently has a `message.client` property on the `message` object which allows you to access your `client` easily. All you need to do to fix your code is add a single line to the top of your `execute()` method in your command file:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'order',
    description: 'Ordering something',
    aliases: ['o'],
    execute(message) {
        const client = message.client; //<- Line added right here

        let order = message.content.substring(8);
        let customer = message.author.id

        fsn.readJSON("./blacklist.json").then((blacklistDB) => {
            let entry = blacklistDB[message.guild.id];
            
            // Checks is server is blacklisted or not.
            if(entry === undefined) {
                // Gets ticket ID.
                const ticketID = generateID();
        
                // Sends ticket information to tickets channel.
                client.guilds.cache.get("745409671430668389").channels.get("746423099871985755").send({embed: {
                    color: 0xFFFFFF,
                    title: message.author.username,
                    fields: [{
                        name: "New Order",
                        value: `${message.author.username} would like to order something.`,
                    }, {
                        name: "Order Description",
                        value: order,
                    }, {
                        name: "Order ID",
                        value: ticketID,
                    }, {
                        name: "Guild Infomation",
                        value: `This order came from ${message.guild} (${message.guild.id}) in ${message.channel} (${message.channel.id}).`,
                    }, {
                        name: "Order Status",
                        value: "Unclaimed", 
                    }],
                    timestamp: new Date(),
                    footer: {
                        text: "Taco Bot"
                    }
                }}).then((m) => {
                    m = m.id;
//rest of the code
```

And that's all! Problem solved. That `message.client` property is amazingly convenient.

Relevant Resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to add the `client` in the `command.execute()` too, because it is easier to use. So you will have:

```js
    try {
        command.execute(client, message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
```

And in every command file you just simply do this.

```js
    execute(client, message, args) {
        //code
    }
```